# Uploading Image to Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to upload an image as a PFFile for a user I have in Parse. I don't get any errors but the file isn't there? What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    self.imageToUpload = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.profileImageView.image = self.imageToUpload;

    NSData *pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageToUpload);

    PFFile *image = [PFFile fileWithName:@"img" data:pictureData];
    [image saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
            user[@"picture"] = image;
            [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error userInfo][@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
    } progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
        NSLog(@"Uploaded: %d%%", percentDone);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually save the `user`, so the link between the user and the new file isn't made. This leaves the file floating around not connected to anything.

Basically, save the `user` after setting `[@"picture"] = image`.

Comment: The user already exists. I'm just allowing them to add/change their picture after they log in.

Comment: Sure, but you need to save the object each time you change it in order to upload the change to the parse server

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.